# Yii2 Csrf on turned off cookies

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, csrf

I have a problem with crsf verification with my AJAX requests on Yii2.
Crsf is allowed in config file

```
 'request'=>array(
        'enableCsrfValidation'=>true,
        'enableCookieValidation'=>true,
    ),
```

and I have this line in main application layout

```
<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
```

All work's normally when cookies is turned on. Also http header have a X-CSRF-Token, witch value is different from cookie's _crsf param.
When I try to disable cookies on my localhost(to test website for nocookie users), ajax request does not work normally. (Error 400 Bad request).
In http request headers I see this line

```
X-CSRF-Token:"U05vc3J6YmVmPgAaFh8gAiMvPBQTETMrBjc8JRA4GywBBwMGAzA7Og=="
```

I saw same value in meta parameters of html page(and for cookie requests too).

Ajax request looks like this. I try to add crsf value to headers and to http param, but there is no effect. Also I have no `beforeAction()` methods

```
   var noCookieResp = $.ajax({
        //beforeSend: function(request){
        //    request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"));
        //},
        type: 'POST',
        url: window.location.origin + '/frontend/web/viewer/noc',
        data: {
            id: postId,
            _csrf : yii.getCsrfToken()
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        },
        success: function(){
            console.log(noCookieResp.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Any suggestions? Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most of case we do not need csrf_token when users disable cookies because them are not logged in. So you can disable csrf in some action or controller where you allow guest access.

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
     $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
     return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Comment: I think this will helps for me. I will add this code to controller's `beforeAction` function for handling ajax requests only:
`if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
            $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
        }
        return parent::beforeAction($action);` But still it will be secure?

Comment: Is it secure, if i'm not using csrf in ajax? Really?

Comment: @frops It is not secure, ajax also can be attack by csrf

Comment: @NgôVănThao If I check csrf on ajax-request, then is secure, I'm wrong?

Comment: @frops I don't know what you mean